# getting issue in docker when i run command docker compose up

Tags: docker

i am new in docker, when i run the command docker-compose up i am getting below error in that

```
+ gpg --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 6E4F6AB321FDC07F2C332E3AC2BF0BC433CFC8B3
gpg: directory `/root/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/root/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 33CFC8B3 from hkp server ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net
?: ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection timed out
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c set -xe   && for key in $GPG_KEYS; do         gpg --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys "$key";     done' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

here i have attached my docker yml file, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ?

```
application:
    build: misc/docker/code
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/seagull
    tty: true
db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor
redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
        - 6379:6379
php:
    build: misc/docker/php-fpm/5.6
    expose:
        - "9000"
    volumes_from:
        - application
    links:
        - db
        - redis
    environment:
      - REDIS_BACKEND=redis:6379
nginx:
    build: misc/docker/nginx
    ports:
        - 80:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - application
    volumes:
        - ./var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
```

Comment: Can’t help much without knowing how your Dockerfile images look like

Answer (score 1):

Keyserver issues are unfortunately very common -- Try a number of different methods, and the only method that's reasonably successful at combating the issue on a large scale is trying multiple keyservers in a loop until one succeeds. Usually, just re-starting the failing build is enough to get it to work, but there may be firewalls, etc in place that force a keyserver switch (`keyserver.ubuntu.com` is a good one that supports port 80 and is commonly allowed).

[@ptsiampas](https://github.com/ptsiampas) Solved by getting it from multiple servers..

```
key='B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4'; \
  gpg  --yes --always-trust --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys "$key" || \
  gpg  --yes --always-trust --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --recv-keys "$key" || \
  gpg  --yes --always-trust --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" ; \
  gpg --batch --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc /usr/local/bin/gosu; \
```

[@camilo0365](https://github.com/camilo0365) Solved it in this way.

```
for server in ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net \
              hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 \
              keyserver.ubuntu.com \
              hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 \
              pgp.mit.edu; do
    gpg --keyserver "$server" --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4 && break || echo "Trying new server..."
done
```

you can use proxy, to solve your problem.

```
gpg --keyserver-options http-proxy="http://XXXXXXX" 
        --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
```

Also for

```
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build:
```

try `docker-compose build --no-cache php-fpm`

Comment: getitng this error ERROR: No such service: php-fpm

Comment: It has to be executed as ```docker-compose exec fpm composer install```. The container is named as `fpm` in the docker compose file.  Refer to [link](https://github.com/ongr-io/development-environment/commit/7a8beccb7be172e68c2e07c20b0b369af0507160)